# Can't manipulate the string in powershell while calling the script in C# Windows Application

Tags: c#-4.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to take backup of SQL Server database using PowerShell and then making windows application around it. But it is not working. I think I have mingled up the strings by putting wrong double quotes and single quotes. Following is the code in C# where I am calling the PowerShell script.

```cs
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking");
pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$dt=Get-Date -Format '" + dtFormat + "' ");
pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$dbname = '" + dbName + "'");
pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$backup = " +bckFolderPath +@"\$($dbname)_db_$($dt).bak");
pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance '" + serverName + "' -Database $dbname -BackupFile" + " $backup");

runspace.Close();
```

What can I do as this is not taking backup but if I run the script in PowerShell, then it is working.

Comment: Can you add the commands you type for PowerShell that are working?

Comment: Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking
$dt = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddHHmmss

$dbname = 'abc'

Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance DEMO -Database $dbname -BackupFile "E:\Backup\$($dbname)_db_$($dt).bak

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that the commands you provided in your comment (that you say are working in PS) aren't the same as the ones you push through c#? The `$backup` line doesn't exist in your PS commands...

Anyway, I believe the error could be in the `$backup` line, missing quotes around the path...

```
pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$backup = '" +bckFolderPath +@"\$($dbname)_db_$($dt).bak'");
```